# IPv6 reverse not resolving for Linux shell "last" and "who"

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, shell, ipv6, reverse-dns

IPv6 is properly resolving in DNS:

```
> host 2607:fa18:0:2::17
7.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.1.a.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa \
  domain name pointer sine.xmission.com.
```

However, the reverse DNS name isn't showing up properly via "last" and "who" on a Linux shell:

```
> who | grep pashdown
pashdown pts/17       2013-03-08 07:30 (2607:fa18:0:2::17)
```

Is there some switch I need to throw for Linux to start resolving IPv6 reverse for logins?

Comment: `sine.xmission.com` does not have a `AAAA` forward record though. Some applications won't trust a `PTR` record unless there exists a forward record that matches it. I don't know whether or not that's the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The "login" program needs forward as well as reverse in order to present the DNS name properly.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on each application. There is no global 'start resolving IPv6 reverse for logins' setting.